# mvc with objective c and c++?

Tags: objective-c, interop, objective-c++

since I like 0 objective c syntax, I heard u can mix objective c and c++. 
So u will use objective c for UI and c++ for the application.

Can i have a code example of how to do this? I mean, on a button click even can i call a c++ method? How can I interact between c++ and objective c?

This may be usefull for an evantual porting to windows for example considering the core application is c++

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with the Objective-C Programming Language [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-TPXREF166). In generall, you can mix Objective-C and C++ code within the same file. Keep in mind this hybrid language (Objective-C++) is much slower to compile and is a C++ superset whereas Objective-C is a C superset, so the usual C vs. C++ differences apply. In general, you are best served by creating an isolated Objective-C++ layer between your pure Objective-C code and your pure C++ code.

In answer to your direct question, the target/action of an `NSControl` cannot be a C++ class method. However, it can be an Objective-C++ class that forward the call to a C++ class method.

Comment: @user495223 There is no performance difference between Objective-C and Objective-C++ at runtime except for your ability to write a better (more efficient) algorithm in one versus the other. There is a significant compile time penalty for Objective-C++.